# which line break for Macs and Windows email apps? \r\n or \n\n

Tags: php

i've read a few other post on here regarding this topic. I understand that `\r\n` is for Windows and `\n` is for Unix so which is recommended for all users? I'm sending out an email and want both Mac and Windows users to have the line break

Comment: It depends on the email client, not necessarily the OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found `\r\n` has issues in Outlook 2007. Using `\n` seems to work in all clients I've tested.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
$headers .= "From: " .  $from . "\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Mail format is specified by RFC:
check out  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt

which says

Messages are divided into lines of characters.  A line is a series of
   characters that is delimited with the two characters carriage-return
   and line-feed; that is, the carriage return (CR) character (ASCII
   value 13) followed immediately by the line feed (LF) character (ASCII
   value 10).  (The carriage-return/line-feed pair is usually written in
   this document as "CRLF".)

So that would be \r\n   Regardless of the mail client.   It isn't the same as a text file stored on the local computer.

Answer (score 0):

\r\n, also known as CRLF (carrage return, line feed) is defined as the correct line ending in RFC 2822.

You may want to use a MIME encoder though to format rich text/html in your email messages.